# Android AccountKit.getCurrentAccount returns "API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument"

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am trying the Facebook AccountKit as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/integrating

I started the AccountKitAcitivity with:

```
AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
                new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                        LoginType.PHONE,
                        AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);
intent.putExtra(
AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
configurationBuilder.build());
startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
```

After I finish the SMS login flow with "verified" at the end, when I call AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(...) in my activity, I am getting "API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument" error.

This can only be "solved" by turning ""App Secret Proof for Server API calls" to off. It makes my app less secure...any suggestion?

Comment: Let me know if you found a solution to this, running into the same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you set "Enable client access token flow" to true, then you will only be returned a code at the end of the login flow. You'll also need to set the ResponseType.CODE. You can then exchange it for a token on your server.

If you have "Require app secret" set to true then the /me (as well as some others) can only be called from the server. getCurrentAccount essentially wraps the /me endpoint and cannot be called then.